# Pointing to structs to store data

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure, fopen

The program is supposed to read from a text file containing an eight digit number (the id) and 5 other numbers (the mark), separated by a single space. But I keep getting the error "request for member 'Students' in '*p', which is of non-class type `char'" when I try to point to the array to store the data?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 5

struct Students {
    char id[10];
    int mark[SIZE];
};

void readdata(Students *p);

int main() {

    int i, j, highesttotal, lowesttotal, highestmark, total, *ptr;
    char htid[10], ltid[10], hmid[10], *p;

    struct Students *q;
    q = (Students *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(Students));

    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("student.txt", "r");
    if(f = NULL) { perror("Error"); exit(20); }

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        fscanf(f,"%s %d", p-> Students.id[i], ptr -> Students.mark[i]);
        i++;
    }

    total = highesttotal = highestmark = 0;
    lowesttotal = 100;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            total += Students.mark[j];
            if(p -> Students.mark[j] > (p -> highestmark)) {
                highestmark = Students.mark[i];
                hmid = (p -> Students.id[j]);
            }
            if(highesttotal < total) {
                highesttotal = total;
                htid = (p -> Students.id[j]);
                total = 0;
            }
            if(lowesttotal > total) {
                lowesttotal = total;
                ltid = (p -> Students.id[j]);
                total = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s %d", ltid, lowesttotal);
    printf("%s %d", htid, highesttotal);
    printf("%s %d", hmid, highestmark);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

> `char htid[10], ltid[10], hmid[10], *p;`

declares that `p` is a pointer to `char`. As such, `*p` is a `char`, which does not have any member data. Did you mean to use `q`?

Comment: I did mean to use q, thanks for spotting that. I've changed the code, and now I'm getting another error, "30: error: invalid use of `struct Students'. I don't think I'm using pointers correctly to check whether  the temporary total of the line is larger than the highesttotal.